# Join or concatenate

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am learning SQL so go easy!

I have a couple of tables. The common column between them is a 'user_id' column. Table 1 has a 'user_name' column. I want to get all the user names from this column in Table 1 where the user_IDs match and update a column in Table 2 named 'domain_info' with: ('domain name\','user_name').
'domain name\' will be text string and 
'user_name' will be from Table 1

All help is much appreciated
Cheers

Comment: that's cool.  Is there a question?

Comment: See [how to post a good question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) or at least read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on this topic so that people can actually help you. DDL and some sample data with expected output would be extremely helpful in all questions. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should **not** `update` that column because then you would have to keep it updated every time the `user_name` changes on the `user` table. This is one of the important concepts of [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) regarding dependencies and redundancy. Instead, stick to just querying the data you need from the tables using their relations.

```
select u.user_name, domain_info = d.domain_info+'\'+u.user_name
from table_1 u
  inner join table_2 d
    on u.user_id = d.user_id
```

---

The update syntax would be:

```
update d
  set domain_info = d.domain_info+'\'+u.user_name
from table_1 u
  inner join table_2 d
    on u.user_id = d.user_id
```

If either are nullable, you can wrap them in `isnull()` or `coalesce()` like so:

```
update d
  set domain_info = isnull(d.domain_info,'')+isnull('\'+u.user_name,'')
from table_1 u
  inner join table_2 d
    on u.user_id = d.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you but this just displays a new column after selecting. I do want to update the second table as the users in it do not change...

Comment: I'm trying to batch load the existing users' domain credentials into the second table. Once done, any changes in the future can be made by the application

Comment: @Goozer16 Updated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SqlZim..

I got it to work like this:

UPDATE
    table2
SET
    table2.domain_info = user_name
    FROM
    table1
WHERE
    table1.user_id = table2.user_id;

UPDATE
    table2
SET
    table2.domain_info = 
    (SELECT {fn CONCAT('domainname\',domain_info)})
WHERE
    user_id = user_id;

I'd be almost certain there is a better syntax for this...I haven't written much TSQL at all. But it worked!

Thanks again